# Ресурс с олимпиадными задачами

Tags: олимпиада

В качестве саморазвития решил порешать задачи спортивного программирования. 
Набрел на сайт - http://acm.timus.ru
То, что нужно - подумал я. Решил задачу, стал смотреть рейтинг решений.. Есть очень быстрые решения, надо посмотреть. И тут столкнулся с проблемой - смотреть решение может только сам решивший.

Собственно, начал искать в интернете архивы задач с решениями.. но не нашел ничего дельного.

Может, кто нибудь знает подобные архивы? Было бы очень интересно посмотреть, как с теми же задачами справляются другие(в том числе более опытные) разработчики.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Главное, не смотреть готовые решения, а уметь вычленять саму суть задачи и искать ее решение. Поэтому, Вам нужны не решения, а алгоритмы. И для них есть большие сборники.

- [Школа программиста](http://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=195)
- [Решения олимпиадных задач](http://school-collection.edu.ru/catalog/rubr/7d5f9dcd-3c0e-c52c-0181-ed064bbfa22d/86787/?interface=themcol)
- [Алгоритмы для олимпиадных задач](http://algolist.manual.ru/olimp/)
- [ещё алгоритмы](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Особенно понравилась четвертый ресурс. 

Да, надо самому уметь вычленять суть. Но у многих задач есть несколько решений, не всегда удается найти лучшее. А если, есть решение лучше, чем я смог придумать и найти - интересно его посмотреть. Исключительно с этой целью и задался целью увидеть такой сборник.

Answer (score 3):

Есть сайт - [codeforces.ru](http://codeforces.ru). Там есть множество задач, проходят постоянно соревнования (вроде каждые 5 дней). Решения можно смотреть других людей, а также публикуются решения задач с объяснениями.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что никто не упомянул [informatics.mccme.ru](http://informatics.mccme.ru). Один из самых популярных. Из плюсов - большая база задач, к тому же классифицированных.

Из минусов - они не показывают тесты к задачам. И ещё они языки поздно добавляют. Java у них только седьмая, C# всё ещё на mono, а скалы и джаваскрипта вообще нет.